# HDFS file Split Command : Spark/Scala using spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I am trying to spllit my csv files into multiple csv part file using spark scala.When i am manulaay executing code its working fine and i am  able to see the part files. But when i m executing same command using jar and trying to submit using spark submit i m getting error like

```
split: can not open 'file_location/filename' for reading No such file or  directory.
```

can someone please guide me what is the issue here.

**code:**

```
val file1 = filelocation/filename
val file2 = file1.replace(".csv","_")
if (fs.exists(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(file1))) {
   s"split -l 20000000 -d --additional-suffix=.csv /hadoop$file1 /hadoop$file2"!
}
```

Comment: Instead of os specific split command.. you can use spark to read file & repartition then write into hdfs ..

Comment: I would support the solution suggested by srinivas. But with respect to your error could you please give the spark submit command as well. Also details on where the file is located and from where you are running the spark submit. Please provide more details